# Confirmation code page is automatically verifying without input

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, verification

My custom Wordpress plugin lets users submit posts of a custom post type from a form on my site. They input the information, click submit, and then they are taken to a Verification page. This instructs them to either click the link that was e-mailed to them or input the code, at which point it goes from Draft to Publish.

This is all working for the most part except after submission. When they are taken to the *Verification* page, it is automatically approving/publishing the post for some reason. I have triple checked the code and it is making absolutely zero sense.

Hoping someone can spot the error because I am at a loss...

Submit Page function

```
function slicer_profile_submit()
{
    // if the submit button is clicked, submit
    if (isset($_POST['slicer-profile-submitted']))
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['slicer-profile']['tmp_name']) or die("Error: Cannot upload file. Please contact the administrator.");
        $contents = $xml->asXML();

        //https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

        // sanitize form values
        $profile_author = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["slicer-profile-author"] );
        $profile_email = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["slicer-profile-email"] );
        $profile_name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["slicer-profile-name"] );
        $profile_description = sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST["slicer-profile-description"] );

        $profile_model = intval($_POST["slicer-profile-model"]);
        $profile_slicer = intval($_POST["slicer-profile-software"]);

        // Create post object
        $slicer_profile = array(
            'post_title'    => $profile_name,
            'post_content'  => $contents,
            'post_type' => 'slicer_profiles',
            'post_status'   => 'draft',
            'post_author'   => 3,
            'tax_input' => array(
                'model'     => array($profile_model),
                'slicer'    => array($profile_slicer)
            ),
            'meta_input' => array(
                'slicer_profile_author' => $profile_author,
                'slicer_profile_description' => $profile_description
            )
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $slicer_profile );

        // Generate a hashed code for the confirmation URL
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $post_id, secret);

        $confirm_url = site_url(). '/verification?id=' . $post_id . '&hash=' . $hash;

        // Send a verification e-mail to the user to confirm publication
        $subject = 'Please confirm your Slicer Profile submission';
        $body = $confirm_url;
        wp_mail( $profile_email, $subject, $body );

        // Redirect the submitter to the post
        wp_redirect( site_url(). "/verification" );
    }
}
```

Verification page function

```
function slicer_profiles_verification_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '')
{
    // Check that both parameters are set
    if( isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash']) )
    {
        $post_id = $_GET['id'];
        $hash = $_GET['hash'];

        $target_hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $post_id, secret);

        // Check if the hash code matches the provided Post ID
        if ($hash != $target_hash)
        {
            echo 'The code provided is incorrect or has been mistyped.';
            return;
        }

        // Get the Post data based on ID
        $post_data = get_post( $post_id ); 
        $post_type = $post_data->post_type;
        $post_status = $post_data->post_status;

        // Check to confirm this is a Slicer Profile post type
        if ($post_type == 'slicer_profiles')
        {
            // If the post has already been published
            if ($post_status == 'draft')
            {
                // Publish the Post by ID
                wp_publish_post($post_id);

                echo 'Thank you, the profile submission has been confirmed.';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'The code provide has already been used.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'The code provide is not a valid submission. Please contact the Administrator.';
        }
    }
    else
    {

    ?>

        <div style="align:center;text-align: center;">
        <p>A confirmation e-mail has been sent to the address provided, containing the verification code to approve your submission. Please use the included link to approve and publish your slicer profile, or the form below the submit your code.</p>

        <form name="confirmSub" method="GET" action="">
            <input type="text" name="id" size="4" /> - <input type="text" name="hash" size="24" /></br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
        </form>

        <?php

        echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode('slicer_profile_verification', 'slicer_profiles_verification_shortcode');
```

Comment: Do you mean that your code is going straight to wp_publish_post($post_id); ?

Comment: @MadeInDreams If I comment out the redirect at the end of the submission page, the post goes to Draft status. If the redirect to the 'verification' page is there, it automatically publishes it.

Comment: And are you sure all the if conditions are met as expected? And the get params are ok to?

Comment: What does $_GET['id'] cotains when redirecting to /verification ?

Comment: I just updated the code, moved the $hash check to the top of the verification function and that seems to have fixed the issue (no idea how/why).

For some reason using the form input at the bottom to verify though (GET FORM) instead of the e-mail link says the code has already been used. It publishes it but shows the wrong message. I have to be missing something here, just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: idk there is something weird with your if and else statement

Comment: I am thinking the same. I may just have to separate them out into individual checks rather than having nested if/else statements. It seems to have fixed whatever was wrong with $hash == $target_hash, will try doing the same with the other checks.

Comment: Yes you have only one valid else statement as it is right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way. The code you have is not going trought all the conditions or else statements.

```
function example() {

  if(you have a post){
    //analyse post value this way
    if(){

    }
    elseif(){

          }
    elseif(){
          }
    else{
      }

}

else{ // you dont have a post
}


}
```

Comment: After MUCH further testing, I narrowed it down to the wp_mail code in the first code block. For some reason my $confirmation_email having the confirm URL is executing it when sent via wp_mail(). I have no idea how to fix it, but it works fine if I eliminate the mail bit.